# How can I parse JSONObject without knowing the name?

Tags: java, android, json

I have json string like this:

```html
{  
    "2":{  
        "id":"2",
        "first":"3",
        "last":"2",
        "ilike":"1",
        "created_at":"2015-06-30 16:57:39",
        "liketo":"2",
        "firstname":"FirstName",
        "lastname":"LastName",
        "birthday":null
    }
}
```

How can I parse JSONObject without knowing the name "2"
just moving to the next array?

Comment: what json parser are you using?

Comment: Depends on your parser.

Comment: Yes you can. First parse the string into `JSONObject` then key the `keySet()` & the iterate over the `keySet()` to get individual objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String json="" // place your json format here in double Quotes with proper escapes .......
jObject = new JSONObject(json.trim());
Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

while( keys.hasNext() ) {
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
         // do what ever you want with the JSONObject.....
    }
}
```